# How to insert data into mysql table using python(MySQLdb)?

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
cur1 = connection.cursor() 
cur3 = connection.cursor() 
cur3.execute("SELECT * FROM TABLE1") 
connection.commit()
for i in range(0,totalRow-1): 
   row = cur3.fetchone() 
   if tempId.__contains__(row[0]): 
      cur1.execute("insert into summary (id, description, resolution) values (%s, %s, %s)",(row[0],row[1],tempResolution[tempId.index(row[0])]))
```

The above code is not giving any error but data is not inserting in the database.

Comment: Please post the whole code.. right now I can't see how you are creating `connection` object and from where you are setting `totalRow`  , `tempId` and `tempResolution`. Program depends on these values to perform correctly.

Answer (score 0):

instead of last line, try this:

```
tuple = row[0], row[1], tempResolution[tempId.index(row[0])]
cur1.executemany("insert into summary (id, description, resolution) values (?,?,?)", tuple)
```

if that doesn't work please expand your code explaining what are `totalRow`, `tempId.__contains__` and types of `row[0]`,`row[1]`,`tempResolution[tempId.index(row[0])]`

Comment: I'm using `with lite.connect('test.db') cur1.executemany(...)` so it works for me without `connection.autocommit(True) `